# Is there a (built in) way to deside if a focus evt is a real change or just a re-focus

Tags: javascript, jquery

There are 2 in my world different situations to get the focus

get focus within window 'focus' (eg. TAB)

get focus (back) after window lost it / gets it back (eg. taskswitch)

The Browser knows while when tabbing the caret is re-positioned (or all selected), while when task switching the focus event fires again, but the cursor position is not changed.

I know that I can solve my problem with looking at the previously focused element and there are many solutions here on SO, but my question is more basic and I don't want to program a workaround if there is a basic solution (although asking this question takes more time). I am not interested in the previously focused element.

I accept an "until now 2017 not possible" answer when explained

Comment: In my practice we've always used a buffer global var to handle that.